# Alert Dialog Edit Text soft keyboard hide the content of the Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I'm a beginner for the android development. This App is used 'CustomDialog' to display two 'EditText' and a 'Spinner' when we click on a 'textView' in a main activity. When we click on the EditText in that dialog, the soft keyboard is appearing and hiding the part of the content of that dialog. This issue will occur to Android version 7.0, not for the law versions.

My code is below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.threeiteam.weightstripz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_bottom_border"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/measurement_height_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/measurement_height_text_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="@string/hint_measurement_height_feet"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/measurement_unit_text_view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ft,"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/measurement_height_text_view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="@string/hint_measurement_height_inches"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/measurement_unit_text_view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="in"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the 'Linearlayout named @+id/measurement_height_layout, the dialog will appear.

**custom_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tittle_text_view"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_first"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="0"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_second"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/error_text_view"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:id="@+id/height_spinner">

        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/height_set_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:gravity="end"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I show above custom_dialog in

**MainActivity.java**

```
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_back_button)
    ImageView measurementBackButton;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_next_text_view)
    TextView measurementNextButton;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_height_text_view1)
    TextView measurementHeightTextView1;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_height_text_view2)
    TextView measurementHeightTextView2;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_weight_text_view)
    TextView measurementWeightTextView;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_height_layout)
    LinearLayout measurementHeightLayout;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_unit_text_view1)
    TextView feetTextView;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_unit_text_view2)
    TextView inchesTextView;

    @InjectView(R.id.measurement_weight_unit_text_view)
    TextView weightUnitTextView;

    private Context context;
    ArrayAdapter<String> tagAdapter;
    private static int heightFeet = 0;
    private static int heightInches = 0;
    private static double heightCenti = 0;
    private static double weightKilo = 0;
    private static double weightPounds = 0;
    private static int weightStone = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_measurement);

        context = this;
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();

            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

            // finally change the color
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorDarkBlue));
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.measurement_height_layout)
    public void getValidHeightValue(){        

            displayHeightDialog("Height", "", "");

    }


    public void displayHeightDialog(String tittle, String feet, String inches){

        if (measurementHeightTextView1.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 && !measurementHeightTextView1.getText().toString().trim().equals("0")){

            heightCenti = 0;

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SignUpMeasurementActivity.this);
            //dialog.setTitle(height);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.measurement_custom_dialog);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(1200, 1200);
            } else {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(400, 400);
            }

            List<String> itemArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            itemArray.add("Feet & Inches");
            itemArray.add("Centimeters");

            final TextView tittleTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tittle_text_view);
            final EditText firstEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_first);
            final TextView firstTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_view_first);
            final EditText secondEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_second);
            final TextView secondTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_view_second);
            final Spinner heightSpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.height_spinner);
            final TextView setButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.height_set_button);
            final TextView errorTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.error_text_view);

//            /firstEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            firstTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            secondEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            secondTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            firstEditText.setText(feet);
            secondEditText.setText(inches);
            firstTextView.setText("ft");
            secondTextView.setText("in");
            errorTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkGreen));
            tittleTextView.setText(tittle);

            tagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemArray);
            heightSpinner.setAdapter(tagAdapter);
            heightSpinner.setSelection(0);

            dialog.show();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

//            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

//            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
//                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//                    imm.showSoftInput(firstEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
//                }
//            });

        }else {

            heightCenti = 0;

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SignUpMeasurementActivity.this);
            //dialog.setTitle(height);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.measurement_custom_dialog);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(1200, 1200);
            } else {
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(400, 400);
            }

            List<String> itemArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            itemArray.add("Feet & Inches");
            itemArray.add("Centimeters");

            final TextView tittleTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tittle_text_view);
            final EditText firstEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_first);
            final TextView firstTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_view_first);
            final EditText secondEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_second);
            final TextView secondTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_view_second);
            final Spinner heightSpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.height_spinner);
            final TextView setButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.height_set_button);
            final TextView errorTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.error_text_view);

            firstEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            firstTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            errorTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkGreen));
            tittleTextView.setText(tittle);

            tagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, itemArray);
            heightSpinner.setAdapter(tagAdapter);
            heightSpinner.setSelection(0);

            dialog.show();

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

//            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

//            dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
//                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//                    imm.showSoftInput(firstEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
//                }
//            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: @Saurabh Vadhva. I changed my manifest.xml, but nothing

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" />

Comment: @Alessandro Verona  I did it. but same issue is occurring.

Comment: found any answers?